# Не понятно условие

Tags: java, kotlin

```
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)//вводим значение с клавиатуры
    val A = mutableListOf<Int>()//создаем изменяемый список
    println("Введите последовательность из 10 цифр")

    for (i in 0 until 10){//от 0 до 10 не включая 10
        A.add(sc.nextInt())//введенное значение заносим в список
    }

    var max = A[0]//создаем переменную max и помещаем в нее 1 элемент списка
    var min = A[0]//создаем переменную min и помещаем в нее 1 элемент списка

    for (element in A){//перебор элементов в списке А
        if (element > max){ //если значение element больше первого элемента в списке
            max = element
        }
        if (element < min){ //если значение element меньше первого элемента в списке
            min = element
        }
    }
    println("Сумма Макс и Мин элементов списка = ${max + min}")
}
```

Не погу понять условие в цикле

```
for (element in A){
 if (element > max)
```

Мы element сравниваем с max, но у element нет никакого значения как можно его сравнивать ?

Comment: В `element` находится значение из списка А на текущей итерации. `println(element)` чтобы убедиться

Comment: @u_mulder т.е. в нем 1 значение которое ввели с клавиатуры вначале?

Comment: Добавьте `println(element)` в цикл `for` и посмотрите.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (element in A){
 if (element > max)
```

если перевести на старый добрый цикл с переменной, становится ясно ( код ниже эквивалентен коду выше)

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    int element = A[i];
    if (element > max) {
        ...
    }
}
```

и как видно, `element` - это по сути каждый элемент из массива